# Temperature estimate from eclipsing binary

Tags: astronomy, thermal-radiation, binary-stars, luminosity, eclipse

So assuming perfect edge on eclipsing binary, we can estimate the temperature ratio of the two stars because the "blocked area" is the same, and thus the amount of light "dimmed" reflects only the temperature.

In the Carroll and Ostilie book, it says "the same total cross sectional area is eclipsed", and then says the amount of light when both stars are visible is some constant times $\pi r^2_s f_{rs} + \pi r^2_l f_{rl}$, where $f_{rs}$ and $f_{rl}$ are surface flux of the two stars.

My question is, why $\pi r^2$? Isn't the actual area blocked a portion of the stellar sphere? The way the book says it it doesn't sound like they're approximating as part of a sphere as a flatten circle, could someone please explain why we only care about the projected area $\pi r^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Earth, the stars will appear (roughly) as uniformly bright disks and the flux received at the Earth will be proportional to the area of that disk multiplied by its surface brightness. The projected area is all that matters here.

The apparent brightness -received flux/projected area - is approximately constant across the visible surface because both the numerator and denominator are changed by inclination to the line of sight by the same $\cos \theta$ factor.

It is a bit more complicated than that though because of [limb darkening](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limb_darkening), which makes the centre of the stellar disk brighter than the edges.

Comment: Are you saying considering it as a disk is an "approximation"?

Comment: @ABC missing words - edited. The stars appear exactly as disks, what is an approximation (in your question) is that they are uniformly bright.

Comment: So let's ignore the limb darkening bit, let's say it's a (half) sphere /uniformly/ emitting the same amount of energy. When we project this sphere onto a flat circle,  wouldn't the "unit area" near the edge of the circle corresponds to a larger area on the actual sphere because of the projection angle? While the "unit area" at the center of the projected circle more or less corresponds to the same "unit area" on the half sphere because the two are pretty much parallel. Wouldn't this cause "nonuniform" surface flux?

Comment: @ABC A bright surface does not change apparent brightness if you tilt it. Both the received flux and the projected area change by the same $\cos \theta$ factor.

Comment: That's it! That's what I wanted to confirm! Thanks!